# SwiftUI Text Badge Bug

Tags: text, swiftui, badge

I found a bug in SwiftUI Badge, it won't work as long as it is nested.
Although this is a new feature of the beta version, but what is the reason? Why can't nesting be used?
It would be greatly appreciated if it can be resolved.

One of the following codes is that the badge is used in the outer layer, and the other is that the badge is not used in the outer layer. The result is that one does not display the right text, and the other displays the right text.

[Nesting effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Eop.jpg)
[Not nested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKWH7.jpg)

```
TabView {
    NavigationView {
        TextBadgeList()
    }
    .tabItem {
        Image(systemName: "rectangle.and.pencil.and.ellipsis")
    }
    .tag(1)
    .badge(99)
    
    NavigationView {
        TextBadgeList()
    }
    .tabItem {
        Image(systemName: "pencil.and.outline")
    }
    .tag(2)
}
.frame(height: 300)
```

TextBadgeList

```
List {
    Section {
        VStack {
            Text("wi-fi")
            Text("No")
        }
        .badge("LAN Solo")
        
        Text("wi-fi")
            .badge("LAN Solo")
        
        Text("wi-fi")
            .badge(900)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is probably a bug. Please report it to Apple

https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=vvrgkboh

---

#### This is a work arround.

Badges are only displayed in `list rows` and `iOS tab bars`. They appear as right-aligned text in a secondary color if used in list rows.

Make a custom `ViewModifier` and use it in list rows.

```
struct CustomBudge: ViewModifier {
    let text: Text
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        HStack {
            content
            Spacer()
            text.foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
        }
    }
}


extension View {
    func customBudge(_ s: String) -> some View {
        self.modifier(CustomBudge(text: Text(s)))
    }
    
    func customBudge(_ number: Int) -> some View {
        self.modifier(CustomBudge(text: Text("\(number)")))
    }
    
    func customBudge(_ text: Text) -> some View {
        self.modifier(CustomBudge(text: text))
    }
}
```

As use it like this

```
struct TextBadgeList2: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                VStack {
                    Text("wi-fi")
                    Text("No")
                }
                .customBudge("LAN Solo")
                Text("wi-fi").customBudge("LAN Solo")
                
                Text("wi-fi").customBudge(900)
                
                Text("Text Budge ").customBudge(Text("test"))
            }.id(UUID())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being late, it is easy to implement this function, I am just thinking about why it doesn't work and whether it can be fixed, because if it can't be used, it is a bug and needs to be fixed.
I submitted feedback FB9486546 and look forward to the result